# Uber Zap logger function name in logs

Tags: go, logging, go-zap

How to get function name printed in logs from Uber Zap logging ?
This is the [PR request](https://github.com/uber-go/zap/pull/844/files) with which they seemed to have added the functionality to output function names in log.

I am using golang version **1.15** and go.uber.org/zap **v1.16.0**

This is my code:

```html
package main

import (
    "go.uber.org/zap"
)

var logger *zap.Logger

func main() {
    logger := NewLogger()
    logger.Info("Test msg Main")
    TestFunc(logger)
}

func TestFunc(logger *zap.Logger)  {
    logger.Info("Test msg TestFunc")
}

func NewLogger() *zap.Logger {
    config := zap.NewDevelopmentConfig()
    opts := []zap.Option{
        zap.AddCallerSkip(1), // traverse call depth for more useful log lines
        zap.AddCaller(),
    }

    logger, _ = config.Build(opts...)
    return logger
}
```

This is the output I get with/without the addition of `AddCaller()` option

```
2021-03-01T15:00:02.927-0800    INFO    runtime/proc.go:204     Test msg Main
2021-03-01T15:00:02.927-0800    INFO    cmd/main.go:12  Test msg TestFunc
```

I am expecting something like

```
   2021-03-01T15:00:02.927-0800    INFO    runtime/proc.go:204   main  Test msg Main
   2021-03-01T15:00:02.927-0800    INFO    cmd/main.go:12  TestFunc Test msg TestFunc
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, the provided encoder presets ([NewDevelopmentEncoderConfig](https://github.com/uber-go/zap/blob/89e382035d3a984a01e6c9c8be5462f11efac844/config.go#L144) used by [NewDevelopmentConfig](https://github.com/uber-go/zap/blob/89e382035d3a984a01e6c9c8be5462f11efac844/config.go#L161-L170) and [NewProductionEncoderConfig](https://github.com/uber-go/zap/blob/89e382035d3a984a01e6c9c8be5462f11efac844/config.go#L104) used by [NewProductionConfig](https://github.com/uber-go/zap/blob/89e382035d3a984a01e6c9c8be5462f11efac844/config.go#L120-L133)) do not enable function name logging.

To enable function name, you need to enable caller (true by default) **and** set a non-empty value for `config.EncoderConfig.FunctionKey`.

Source: [EncoderConfig](https://github.com/uber-go/zap/blob/89e382035d3a984a01e6c9c8be5462f11efac844/zapcore/encoder.go#L312-L336)

```golang
type EncoderConfig struct {
    // Set the keys used for each log entry. If any key is empty, that portion
    // of the entry is omitted.
    ...
    CallerKey     string `json:"callerKey" yaml:"callerKey"`
    FunctionKey   string `json:"functionKey" yaml:"functionKey"` // this needs to be set
    StacktraceKey string `json:"stacktraceKey" yaml:"stacktraceKey"`
    ...
}
```

**Example Console Logger:**

```golang
func main() {
    config := zap.NewDevelopmentConfig()
    // if you're using console encoding, the FunctionKey value can be any
    // non-empty string because console encoding does not print the key.
    config.EncoderConfig.FunctionKey = "F"
    logger, _ := config.Build()
    logger.Info("Test Logging")
    // Output: 2021-03-03T11:41:47.728+0800    INFO    example/main.go:11     main.main       Test Logging
}
```

**Example JSON Logger:**

```golang
func main() {
    config := zap.NewProductionConfig()
    // the FunctionKey value matters because it will become the JSON field
    config.EncoderConfig.FunctionKey = "func"
    logger, _ := config.Build()
    log(logger)
    // Output: {"level":"info","ts":1614743088.538128,"caller":"example/main.go:15","func":"main.log","msg":"Test Logging"}
}

func log(logger *zap.Logger) {
    logger.Info("Test Logging")
}
```